# jQuery load(function) for a Microsoft Word Document

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is for a school project the course is online and not very accurate anymore. I want to use the .load(function) combined with a .click function so when I click the corresponding word I get the corresponding text below in the content div this is my code so far (not very good I will admit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var massage=('massage.docx')
    $('.selection').click(function() {
        $('.selection').load(massage.docx)

    });
});
</script>
```

I want to make it so when i click it puts it in the "content" div at the top before the other text.

Comment: What browser are you using? You're on *localhost*, *server*, *file* ? .load might not work from *file*

Answer (score 1):

From the `jQuery` documentation: https://api.jquery.com/load/

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML
>   into the matched element.

This isn't going to work for you because you're using a `.docx` file type which is not going to return html (or even regular text).  It might manage to do *something* but the output is likely to be garbled.  Do you have this `massage.docx` file on the server?

The following won't work at all:

```
$('.selection').load(massage.docx)
```

I think what you meant is (note that you must use a string here):

```
$('.selection').load("massage.docx")
```

But this still won't work because you are trying to load a microsoft word document as HTML, and that just simply won't function properly.  You should convert your massage.docx either to regular text, or to an html file - upload it to the server in the same location that you are calling this javascript from, and try this again.

Also, use your browser's javascript console to check for JS errors.  In chrome you can do this by right clicking anywhere, selecting "inspect element", and switching to the "Console" tab on the inspector tool.

EDIT:

If you want to make sure the click is even working at all, you might want to add some checks:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var massage=('massage.docx');
    $('.selection').click(function() {
        alert("Clicked!  Attempting to load...");
        $(this).load(massage, function(){
            alert("Loading finished!");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The load would be asynchronous making the "Loading finished!" print inaccurate. It would be more accurate as: `$(".selection").load("massage.docx", function() { alert("Loading Finished!"); });`.

Answer (score -1):

try with txt document first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.selection').click(function() {
        $('.selection').load('test.txt');

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I never used docx and dont know what files jquery supports to load. And it looks like he might wanna load message.docx and not massage.docx lol

Comment: It is for a Spa and Beauty Salon site I am creating for my project, it is massage.txt I changed it to, however, I think the problem actually lies in my div tags...cause they're not clickable right now for some reason. <div id="content">
         <div id="spaselection">
            
                 <p class="selection">
                    Massage
                    Facials 
                 Laser Hair Treatment/Electrolysis 
                 Nails
                    </p>
                  
            </div>

Comment: you should set the div width and height to 200px and a background-color:#ddd; also you can add alert('clicked'); at top of the click function

Comment: Well damn you really did mean `massage.docx`!  Hahaha.

Comment: As Roko pointed out, this has nothing to do with the question which is specifically asking about a `.docx` file not `.txt`.

Comment: you can try load the docx if you want to :)